# App Bundle (AAB) and Opaque Binary Blob (OBB) files

Tags: android, google-play

I've got a question for the new AAB file format.

Until now we can use APK and OBB files to split our binaries from the assets. But after uploading a AAB file, I'm not able to upload an OBB file.

What can I do, if I want to use AAB and OBB? What's the best practice for that now?

Comment: There is currently no support for OBB files with the Android App Bundle. Still working on it, stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support for OBB files with the Android App Bundle. However, the Google Play team hope to add support for this in the very near future.

---- Edit
A year later and Google has [just announced at Google I/O 2019](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/whats-new-in-play.html) customizable feature delivery. The hope is that this will do everything OBBs did but much more. See [all the details here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#customize_delivery).

- at-install delivery is like OBBs - parts of your app that get installed when your App does. Except that you can have more different parts, not just 2.
- on-demand delivery lets you install parts of your app later.

Comment: A lot of work has happened since then, and it was mostly announced at Google I/O this week. The short answer is read the docs for at-install delivery and on-demand delivery https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#customize_delivery
This is like OBB but more flexible - you can configure parts of your app to be delivered at different times. ANd you aren't restricted to just two OBBs. Check it out! https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/whats-new-in-play.html

Comment: So does this mean that OBB support for app bundles is dropped?
For those of us with large payloads (visually-oriented games, not just ui-based apps with extra features) we don't really have the liberty of working with on-demand delivery proprietary to Google Play when we have numerous other stores and platforms to worry about.